# Xamarin - Cross Platform Unit Testing #2

Tags: c#, ios, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

This is a [common question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550090/xamarin-cross-platform-unit-testing), it's really quite astounding to me how difficult such a simple task is turning out to be ...

I have a Visual Studio (formerly Xamarin) C# cross-platform library.  It has some code in the shared "abstract" library, and a few machine-specific implementation classes for Android, iOS, and UWP libraries.  It also has a few automated (non-UI) unit tests that use the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting package.  This is a great start, when Visual Studio 2017 is feeling generous it runs my unit tests and life is good.

Now I want to run the unit tests on simulators of the actual devices, from a command line (so I can run them from Jenkins and capture the output).  So, for example, I want to run my unit tests on a simulator of an iPad.  From various web sites I get the feeling that I can't use the Microsoft package for this, so I need to switch to either Xunit or NUnit.  I gave up on Xunit earlier today, here's how NUnit went.

1. Go into the Unit Test project and remove the NuGet packages for Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk, MSTest.TestFramework, and MSTest.TestAdapter.
2. Add NUnit instead (version 3.7.0).
3. Go into each CS file, change to "using NUnit.Framework", change [TestMethod] to [Test], and [TestClass] to [TestFixture].
4. Project:Manage NuGet Packages, add the NUnit3TestAdapter.
5. Test Explorer: Run All

At this point I get this weird error for the UWP machine-specific library:

```
The "XamlCTask" task could not be initialized with its input parameters
The "DebugType" parameter is not supported by the "XamlCTask" task.  Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
```

That's a really strange message, and if I Rebuild the UWP library, it rebuilds without errors.  Not sure why it's building the UWP library as part of the Unit Tests, the only thing listed under "Projects" is the abstract (non-machine-specific) library.

Also strange that building the Unit Test library works, it's only when I do the Test Explorer: Run All that I get these errors.

OK fine, it's a [known error](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95818/error-executing-task-xamlctask-task-does-not-have-property-debugtype-defined).

Close VS2017, delete bin and obj folders, reopen, no better. Close VS2017, hack the Xamarin.form.targets as listed.  Same error.  Realize error is in the global Xamarin.Forms.targets, not the one in my solution.  Hack it.  Close & reopen solution, rebuild.  No error this time!

Test Explorer: Run all.  Nothing.  Output:Build shows no failures, Output:Tests is completely empty.  Close & reopen solution.  Get new errors:

```
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Workspace\PopComm.iOS\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Workspace\PopComm.iOS\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Workspace\PopComm.iOS\obj\Debug\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs'.
```

Test Explorer: Run all.  This time get more interesting errors:

```
------ Discover test started ------
NUnit Adapter 3.7.0.0: Test discovery starting
Assembly contains no NUnit 3.0 tests: 
C:\Workspace\PopComm.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\PopComm.dll
NUnit Adapter 3.7.0.0: Test discovery complete
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.0530024) ==========
```

Of course that assembly doesn't contain any unit tests!  It's not my unit test project!

Sigh.

OK, create a new project of type "NUnit 3 Unit Test Project".  Move my test classes into this new project and add a dependency to my non-machine-specific library.

Test Explorer: Run all - Tests!  There are tests!  And they even run successfully.

Close VS2017, open again, Test Explorer: Run all.  No tests.  Output:Tests is empty.

Close project, delete all bin and obj folders, Rebuild Solution, Test Explorer: Run All.  No tests.

Push code to git, pull on the Mac.

Open solution in Visual Studio for the Mac.

Use the mostly-hidden View:Test feature to bring up the Unit Tests window, run the tests.  Tests found and run.  Yippee!

Now I want to run my unit tests on an iPad simulator, not inside VSMac.

Add a new project to my solution, type iOS:Tests:Unified API:Unit Test App.

Wizard asks what is the minimum iOS version I want to support.  I figure I should match the iOS version that my machine-specific library targets, so I go looking in the VSMac options for the project.  The iOS target version isn't shown anywhere.  Use the default (10.3) for the Unit Test App.

Do I have to copy all of my unit test CS files into this new app now?  Or can I somehow reference my cross-platform unit test project in this Unit Test App?

Pushing everything and pulling on the Windows machine, I try adding a reference to my unit test library but get an error:

```
The project 'NUnit.Tests' cannot be referenced.  The referenced project is targeted to a different framework family (.NETFramwork)
```

Hum.  I wonder what framework the new NUnit.Tests.iOS application is targeting.  Check its options - it doesn't say anywhere.  Remove the reference from the Unit Test App back to the unit test files, and just copy the unit test source files over (non-optimal).

Run the application in the iPad simulator, it finds & runs the tests, but I don't know how to (1) run it from the command line, and (2) capture the unit test statuses in a file.

So after all this, I still don't know how to run my unit tests (1) from the command line, (2) on an iPad simulator, and (3) capturing the output in a text file.